# Direction to Environment Map UV Coordinates

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, direct3d

I'm trying to render an environment map as a sphere surrounding the scene. I would like to be able to sample the environment map, as a panoramic photo, using UV coordinates derived from a direction vector (where the origin is fixed at (0,0,0)).

How can I project the direction to calculate 2D UV coordinates, so I can sample the environment map?

Comment: At first, you need to know what projection is used for the panoramic photo. This is basically what you want to do for the calculation of texture coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

Calculating texture coordinates for reflection map or environment map is here.

```
    vec3 r = reflect( -vEyeVec, N );
    float m = 2. * sqrt(pow( r.x, 2. ) + pow( r.y, 2. ) + pow( r.z + 1., 2.0));
    vReflectionCoord = r.xy / m + .5;
    vReflectionCoord.y = -vReflectionCoord.y;
```